# Mongodump not working well with Atlas cluster

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, mongodump

When I run mongodump on one of my clusters in Atlas it throws the following error:

```
root@anuj-exportify-EXP02:/home/anuj/Exportify/DataMigration# mongodump --uri="mongodb+srv://<USERNAME>:<PASSWORD>@<CLUSTER-NAME>.mongodb.net/exportifydb"
2023-01-17T13:51:44.172+0530    writing exportifydb.schedules to 
2023-01-17T13:51:44.173+0530    writing exportifydb.automated_logs to 
2023-01-17T13:51:44.173+0530    writing exportifydb.automated_logs_bkp to 
2023-01-17T13:51:44.173+0530    writing exportifydb.logs to 
2023-01-17T13:51:44.190+0530    Failed: error writing data for collection `exportifydb.automated_logs` to disk: error reading collection: Failed to parse: { find: "automated_logs", skip: 0, snapshot: true, $db: "exportifydb" }. Unrecognized field 'snapshot'.
```

My MongoDB version is 5.0.23 on the atlas cluster and the MongoDB version on my local PC is 4.4.3

Should this cause a problem?

Comment: What version of mongodump?

Comment: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/215534/mongodump-unrecognized-field-snapshot